# arcpy.RegionGroup fails with error 999999. Workspace or data source is read only

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, spatial-analyst, error-999999

outRegionGrp = RegionGroup(inRaster,"EIGHT", "WITHIN", "ADD_LINK", valToIgnore)

arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Workspace or data source is read only.
The table was not found. [VAT_RegionG_Con_1]
A column was specified that does not exist.
The table was not found. [VAT_RegionG_Con_1]
The operation was attempted on an empty geometry.
ERROR 010274: Error in writing to table.
ERROR 010067: Error in executing grid expression.
Failed to execute (RegionGroup).

While workspace is at c drive, this error occurs. But while workspace is at other drives, this error does not happen.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *  

env.outputCoordinateSystem = spatialReferance
env.scratchWorkspace = workspacePath
env.workspace = workspacePath

try:
    checkExtensionStatus = arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial")

    if checkExtensionStatus != "Available" :
        raise LicenseError(checkExtensionStatus)

    checkOutExtensionStatus = arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

    if checkOutExtensionStatus != "CheckedOut" :
        raise CheckOutExtensionException(checkOutExtensionStatus)

    outRegionGrpRaster = RegionGroup(inRaster, "EIGHT", "WITHIN", "ADD_LINK", inputFalseConstantValue)
finally:
    arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")
```

Comment: This sounds like an issue with file permissions on your computer, as opposed to any error in your script. Could you post the full code to see if we can find a better solution?

Comment: this code acts fine when workspace is at any other drive without c. If workspace is at c drive, code gives this error.

Comment: What is the exact path on the c drive?  Many functions will fail if the path and/or filename contain spaces.

Comment: I use ""(double quote) for the path name. And this problem occurs for some raster files. some raster files work well in c drive.

Comment: i found the exact same problem -- throws error on C: but not on other drives. probably an ArcGIS error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this problem occurs for some raster files and others not, you might check the length of the name of the raster file.
I remember also having that problem, but I don't remember if the magic name length was 8,11 or 13 characters.
I know it sounds odd these days to have short names, but nevertheless might be worth to test.